# C++ Custom Console doesn't allow input or Lua print or io.write

Tags: c++, winapi, lua, linker

I am currently working with Win32 API along with Lua . I am using an old framework which I have used for previous small projects .
At this stage I have a Win32 Window from the Win32 API . But the problem is that , I wanted to have a Debug Console , similar to that of GLFW and GLEW . So I decided to write my own . But for some reason , its not really functional . The major issue with it right now is that it doesnt recognize or print anything from Lua functions from Lua scripts when i link C++ and Lua together 
Below is the that code which I use for the console

```
void AbstractWindow::MakeDebugConsole(void)
{
    #if _DEBUG
        DWORD mode;
        _CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbi;
        HANDLE h_console;
        FILE* stream;
        // Allocates a new console for the calling process.
        AllocConsole();
        // Set the title for the console window.
        SetConsoleTitle("DEBUG CONSOLE");
        // Retrieve handle to standary input device
        h_console = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        // Retrieves the current input mode of a console's input buffer
        // Or the current output mode of a console screen buffer.
        GetConsoleMode(h_console, (LPDWORD)&mode);
        // Sets the input mode of a console's input buffer
        // Or the output mode of a console screen buffer.
        SetConsoleMode(h_console, mode & 0xFFFFFFEF);
        // Retrieves information about the specified console screen buffer.
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h_console, &sbi);
        // Set the size of the console screen buffer, 
        sbi.dwSize.Y = 500;
        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(h_console, sbi.dwSize);
        // Reassign file pointer
        (&stream, "conin$", "r", stdin);
        freopen_s(&stream, "conout$", "w", stdout);
        freopen_s(&stream, "conout$", "w", stderr);
    #endif
}
```